# Problem with abbreviated name of organizations with bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I use a bib file to specify all my bibliography entries. The journal display the list of entries in the bibliography in the form:

```
Einstein, A. "A...."
```

where the entry is something like:

```
@article{ref
  AUTHOR={Einstein, Albert},
  TITLE={A...},
  ...
}
```

Now, when the author is something like:

```
@article{anotherref
  AUTHOR={United Nations},
  TITLE={A report on...},
  ...
}
```

this entry is reported as

```
U. Nations "A report on..."
```

How can I make the author name for this special cases to be shown without no abbreviations? I.e., I need:

```
Einstein, A. "A...."
```

but I also need:

```
United Nations. "A report on..."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put it in curly brackets:

```
AUTHOR={{United Nations}}
```

This will prevent it from being taken apart.